# Process hogging CPU

Tags: process

what is `udpate-apt-xapi`?

I was browsing when all of a sudden, the above process spawns using 100% CPU and fan becomes louder. After a minute or so, it automatically subsides.

From the name, I guess it is somehow related to `apt`, but why would it start automatically when I had just updated few hours ago and the update interval is set to 2 days.

P.S. -  Ubuntu 10.10, 2.6.35.22

Answer (score 3):

It rebuilds the index of packages used to list packages and applications in Add/Remove Applications and Synaptic.

And yes, it can be a problem, especially for old computers.
If you want to disable it, this is what worked for me, as I remember:

> sudo chmod 644 /etc/cron.weekly/apt-xapian-index
>   It makes the file not executable.

Check [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1102483) for more info and other solutions.

Answer (score -1):

This rebuilds the list of packages for Software Center and Synaptic etc. If it is not a problem you can just let it run. I looked at a way to disable it and it seems out of date. My apologies for not being very helpful. I will add comments if I learn more.

Comment: If you have more information to add, feel free to edit your answer rather than just add comments :)

Comment: True. Thanks, that will probably be more organized.